# How to prevent double items but also prevent entire list from refreshing?

Tags: android

I am getting a JSON Array of user ids strings from a database:

```
["uid1", "uid103", "uid322"]
```

I am fetching this array on a time triggered loop, and I use `notifyDataSetChanged` with `myDataSet.clear()` to display the list, and to prevent duplicates. The problem with this method is that the list is constantly "refreshing", and I just want to either add or remove the items that's needed to be removed or added.

If I remove the `clear()` part, then the list won't refresh, but I will get duplicate items.

This is how the code (+pseudo) looks like:

```
trigger(just a time based loop) {  
    myDataset.clear();
    jsonArray = //the id array from the database;

    for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length;i++){                                                                                        
        myDataset.add(new User(jsonArray.get(i), imageUrl));                                                 
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: move mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() out of the loop

Comment: Then how will the list know if it's changed or not? It's not the problem

Comment: calling notifyDataSetChanged every time in a loop is still really bad. Just call it once outside of the loop

Answer (score 0):

You can use for this purpose [DiffUtil](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil) class ([Medium example](https://medium.com/@iammert/using-diffutil-in-android-recyclerview-bdca8e4fbb00)).

It calculates differences between new and old datasets and updates it.

But if you don't want to deep dive into DiffUtil you can try to use combination of `notifyItemInserted()` and `notifyItemChanged()`

Comment: But how? And if the item is removed and not inserted?

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as below, Your loop will do all the changes in your data and once the loop is over you notify those changes to your list in one go, instead of refreshing it each time.

```
for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length;i++){                                                                                        
    myDataset.add(new User(jsonArray.get(i)));                                                 
}
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

If you want to avoid duplicates use `Set`, add items to set from your json array and use it as datasource for your list.

Comment: But every time I use `new User`, it will add new item in the list, even if it's the same id, because it's a new User instance

Comment: `notifydatasetchanged()` will notify all changes done to dataset in one go.

Comment: But I want to prevent duplicates. . .

Comment: how it prevents duplicates if you notify one item at a time?

Comment: if you want to avoid duplicates use `Set`, add items to set from your json array and use it as datasource for your list.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare the 2 lists before refreshing. So,

- If an item is removed, Your list's size will be smaller.
- If an item is added, the list's size will be bigger and the new item will be the last item in the retrieved array.
- But if an item is removed and at the same time an item is added, your list's size will be the same but the last item will change.
  So, you need to check both array size and the last item before refreshing like this:

  ```
  trigger(just a time based loop) {  
      if((myDataset.size() != jsonArray.size()) || myDataset[last] != jsonArray[last]) {
              myDataset.clear();
              jsonArray = //the id array from the database;

              for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length;i++){                                                                                        
                  myDataset.add(new User(jsonArray.get(i)));                                                 
                  mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
              }
          }
      }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You have a basic misunderstanding of the timer trigger. The loop will not pause there waiting for your next User entry from JSON. So adding notify in the loop is very bad practice. One notify outside the loop is enough. If a new User is added, it should appear in another timer trigger, i.e., another loop.

If you are seeing duplicate, that must be in the code handling the JSON to insert your database. However this code is not listed here so you need to look at that code.

Adding a unique index in the database table is a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

for avoiding duplicate use contains

```
   myDataset.clear();
for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length;i++){    
 User user=new  User(jsonArray.get(i), imageUrl);                                                                                    
 //now check if its already in list or not by using contains.  
 if(!myDataset.contains(user)){
  myDataset.add(user)
  }                                            

}//end of loop
```

and then pass list to your adapter and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

```
 mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```